# why my flutter page is getting slow after adding a future builder code to my listview

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

app was working fine all pages working fine but a single page is getting slow after adding this code to my listview

```
 leading: FutureBuilder<Uint8List?>(
                      future: _thumbnailImage(files[index].path),
                      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<Uint8List?> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Image.memory(snapshot.data!);
                        }
                        return Text("error");
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

`FutureBuilder` waits for the data. Until the future function `_thumbnailImage(files[index].path)` doesn't return the data, `ListView` (leading property) won't be build.

Note that `FutureBuilder` will impact only where it is used. Other widgets should be loaded normally.